# How do I manage console output in a long running Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin, console

I have written an Eclipse plugin that works.  What happens, though, is that during the run, no console output is displayed.  Only when the process is finished does the output show up in the console.  Below is my handler, which appears as an extension point of type org.eclipse.ui.commands:

```
public class MyHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        ...
        MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
        ...
        IConsoleView view = (IConsoleView) page.showView(id);
        view.display(myConsole);
        ...

        out.println("output that only shows up at the end");
        myConsole.activate();
        ...
        // Slow process
        ...
        out.println("everything is done");
        return null;
    }
}
```

So while the process runs, nothing in the console.  Then at the end, both output lines pop into view.

I'm obviously doing the console thing incorrectly, but I haven't found any good examples, nor has my experimentation proven very fruitful.  Please advise.

Comment: @anq, It's not in the question, but I did try flush in the 'real' code.  I had to put it in a "Job" and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
public class Merge extends AbstractHandler {
private static MessageConsole myConsole = null;
private static ExecutionEvent event = null;

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    Merge.event = event;

    //same idea as original post and other examples where it makes new or finds existing
    myConsole = makeConsole(Merge.event); 

    Job job = new Job("My Job Name"){
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor){
            ...
            if (blah) {
                MessageConsoleStream out = myConsole.newMessageStream();
                out.println("output show up right away");
                ...
                // Slow process
                ...
                out.println("everything is done");
            } else {
                MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(Merge.event), "Information", "Please select valid file");
            }
            monitor.done();
            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.setUser(true);
    job.schedule();
    return null;
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a [`ProgressMonitor`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_progress_monitors?) (possibly with cancelation in case the user wants to abort), so that the user can see that there is something going on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call out.flush() after every out.print...